# If we have different id in span is there any to provide them similar color using css?

Tags: html, css

```html
<span id="roll1">this is someone </span>
<span id="roll2">this is someone c </span>
<span id="roll3">this is someone b </span>
<span id="roll4">this is someone a </span>
<span id="roll5">this is someone d </span>
<span id="roll6">this is someone e</span>
<span id="roll7">this is someone f</span>
```

How can I provide same color to all these id using a external `CSS` file?

Comment: add one class name in all span and add color in that class like this: `.red {color: red}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), id^='roll' means id begins with `roll`

```css
span[id^='roll'] {
  color: green;  
}
```

```html
<span id="roll1">this is someone </span>
<span id="roll2">this is someone c </span>
<span id="roll3">this is someone b </span>
<span id="roll4">this is someone a </span>
<span id="roll5">this is someone d </span>
<span id="roll6">this is someone e</span>
<span id="roll7">this is someone f</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add one class name in all span and add color in that class like this: `.red {color: red}`

```css
.red{
  color: red;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span id="roll1" class="red">this is someone </span>
<span id="roll2" class="red">this is someone c </span>
<span id="roll3" class="red">this is someone b </span>
<span id="roll4" class="red">this is someone a </span>
<span id="roll5" class="red">this is someone d </span>
<span id="roll6" class="red">this is someone e</span>
<span id="roll7" class="red">this is someone f</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If all ids start with `roll` you can try something like this `span[id^=roll]` `^=` denotes selector start with.

```css
span[id^=roll] {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="roll1">this is someone </span>
<span id="roll2">this is someone c </span>
<span id="roll3">this is someone b </span>
<span id="roll4">this is someone a </span>
<span id="roll5">this is someone d </span>
<span id="roll6">this is someone e</span>
<span id="roll7">this is someone f</span>
```

Another approach is to add a wrapper element and target the child elements.

**Example**

```css
.roll-container > span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="roll-container">
  <span id="roll1">this is someone </span>
  <span id="roll2">this is someone c </span>
  <span id="roll3">this is someone b </span>
  <span id="roll4">this is someone a </span>
  <span id="roll5">this is someone d </span>
  <span id="roll6">this is someone e</span>
  <span id="roll7">this is someone f</span>
</div>
```

> how can i provide same color to all these id using a external css
> file?

You can also target the ids directly.

```
#roll1, #roll2, #roll3, #roll4, #roll5, #roll5, #roll6, #roll7 {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="spancolor">
    <span id="roll1">this is someone </span>
    <span id="roll2">this is someone c </span>
    <span id="roll3">this is someone b </span>
    <span id="roll4">this is someone a </span>
    <span id="roll5">this is someone d </span>
    <span id="roll6">this is someone e</span>
    <span id="roll7">this is someone f</span>
  </div>
```

**Your CSS File :**

```
.spancolor {
   color:#FFFFFF;
  }
```